Transcendental Basis and (Transcendental) Separable Extension
Fix $p$ as the characteristic of fields. A $p$-basis of a field $K$ is  $\{b_1,\cdots,b_e\}\subseteq K$ such that $\{\prod_{i\in I}b_i^{k_i}\,|\,0\leq k_i\leq p-1\}$ is a $K^p$-basis in the $K^p$-vector space $K$. The terminology "$p$-independence" can be similarly defined, by replacing "basis" with "independence". A field extension $L/K$ is separable, if a $p$-basis of $K$ is $p$-independent in $L$.
I want to show that:

If $L/K$ is algebraic, then it is separable iff every element in $L$ has a separable minimal polynomial over $K$.

If $L=K(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ is separable over $K$, then there is a transcendental basis $\overline{a}'\subseteq\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ such that $L$ is separable algebraic over $K(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$.


I do not know how to continue from here.

For 1., firstly note that $L/K$ is separable iff $L$ and $K^{-1}$ are linearly disjoint over $K$ iff $L$ and $K^\text{perf}$ are linearly disjoint over $K$.
Assume that $L/K$ is algebraic and separable. Then $L$ and $K^{-1}$ are linearly disjoint over $K$ and for any $\alpha\in L$ with minimal polynomial $f=\sum_{i=1}^na_iX^i\in K[X]$, all the coefficients $a_i$ are of the form $b_i^p$ for some $b_i\in K^{-1}$. Hence, if such a $f$ is not separable, then $f=g(X)^p$ for some $g(X)\in K^{-1}[X]$ and by linearly disjointness, $g(X)$ can be replaced with $g_1(X)\in K[X]$, which contradicts minimality of $f$. Conversely, if $L/K$ is algebraic and every element in $L$ has a separable minimal polynomial, without loss of generality, we show that $K^\text{sep}$ and $K^\text{perf}$ are linearly disjoint over $K$, which will imply that $L$ and $K^\text{perf}$ are linearly disjoint over $K$. This is clear, because $K^\text{sep}/K$ is Galois and then the linearly disjointness is equivalent to $K^\text{sep}\cap K^\text{perf}=K$.
